# How get new column in CSV (PHP or MySQL) containing hierarchy of product categories?

Tags: php, mysql

I have in my MySQL database two simple tables: **category** и **product**:

[image: category:]
[image: product:]

How can I get final CSV file (by PHP or MySQL or any variant) with new column containing hierarchy of **category** table like below?

[image: final CSV]

Comment: No pictures, thanks. See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score -1):

You could the MySQL GROUP_CONCAT function. Assuming that category.parent_id links to product.product_id, the following query should work.

SELECT product.*, GROUP_CONCAT(category.name,'-') from category INNER JOIN product ON (category.parent_id=product.product_id) GROUP BY category.parent_id